# Is it Racism or Stereotyping when unfairly judging a culture?

Tags: meaning

I was recently in a debate about unfair judgement of a culture by what it produces. the examples were

- Because something looks Arabic it's Muslim and is Terrorist Material (because of ISIS)
- Because something looks Japanese it's pornographic (because of Hentai)
- Because something looks German it's represents Nazism (because if the Nazis)

I debated these are just very unfair stereotyping by most likely exaggerating one example however the person I was having the debate with said that it was actually racism as the categorization of something from a culture as something bad is making that culture and to the extent it's people inferior. ie,

- All Arabs are Muslim and all Muslims are terrorists
- The Japanese can only make pornographic things and are all perverts
- The Germans still hold onto their Nazi history and thus are Nazis

Seeing it like this it sorta looks like racism to me. So is it Racism or Stereotyping when unfairly judging a culture like this?

Comment: There are contexts where the primary intention/effect of ***stereotyping*** is to put stereotyped individuals in a *better* position than they would otherwise have been. I'm not sure that ever occurs with ***racism***, which is *always* about putting the "different" race at a *disadvantage*. Whatever - these two words have obviously different dictionary definitions, so this question just looks like an invitation to discuss the issues, not the meanings of the words themselves.

Comment: Racism is a subset of stereotyping.

Comment: What does your question have to do with the English language?

Comment: All those examples are examples of  synecdoches.

Comment: To reviewers: I see 4 votes to close. I'd recommend keeping this question open - the answer below draws out the nuance between stereotyping and racism, as does @FumbleFingers' comment above. Identifying that difference is the essence of the question.

Comment: @Lawrence: I'd say the difference between stereotyping and racism is hardly a "nuance". Any dictionary would give definitions for both that should make it clear what the words actually *mean*, regardless of whether some people use them loosely.  Personally, I think if we accept OP's starting position here (that *stereotyping + racism* might be considered synonymous), we may as well say the same about *Arab + terrorist, Japanese + pervert* and *German + Nazi*, which is plainly ridiculous. It's just an invitation to discussion, without reference to dictionary definitions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm thinking of the overlap in racial profiling, which seems to be the context of the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

Stereotyping is a form of pre-judging a person based upon a common action or characteristic of other individuals of that same race.  While it may be accurate for some, it does not define an entire race (e.g. all blacks are great basketball players, criminals, violent, etc.)  The "pre-judging" action is the basis of what we define as "prejudice."

Racism is the act of using any type of power (e.g. hiring, legislative, mass communications, law enforcement, conducting business, teaching, etc.) that one may possess to take actions against or not in favor of a particular group based upon racial prejudices that the holder of power may hold. (e.g. targeted police brutality, predatory lending/redlining, voting restrictions, housing discrimination, employment discrimination, etc.).  While this is a limited list of examples, the actions of racists can be expanded to many other ideas and activities.  The core definition of racism is "power through prejudices."

Comment: +1 for linking *stereotype* with *perception* and *racism* with *activity*.

Comment: The two are closely related, though: racist policies and actions are often due to opinions that derive from stereotyping.